# How can I merge two files by column with awk?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have the two following text files:

file1

```
-7.7
-7.4
-7.3
-7.3
-7.3
```

file2

```
4.823
5.472
5.856
4.770
4.425
```

And I want to merge them side by side, separated by a comma:

file3

```
-7.7,4.823
-7.4,5.472
-7.3,5.856
-7.3,4.770
-7.3,4.425
```

I know this can be easily done with `paste -d ',' file1 file2 > file3`, but I want a solution that allows me to have control over each iteration, since my dataset is big and I also need to add other columns to the output file. E.g.:

```
A,-7.7,4.823,3
A,-7.4,5.472,2
B,-7.3,5.856,3
A,-7.3,4.770,1
B,-7.3,4.425,1
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$count]=$1; count+=1; next} {print a[$count] "," $1; count+=1;}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Output:

```
-7.3,4.823
-7.3,5.472
-7.3,5.856
-7.3,4.770
-7.3,4.425
```

I am new to bash and awk, so a detailed response would be appreciated :)

Edit:
Suppose I have a directory with pairs of files, ending with two extensions: .ext1 and .ext2. Those files have parameters included in their names, for example file_0_par1_par2.ext1 has its pair, file_0_par1_par2.ext2. Each file contains 5 values. I have a function to extract its serial number and its parameters from its name. My goal is to write, on a single csv file (file_out.csv), the values present in the files along with the parameters extracted from their names.
Code:

```
for file1 in *.ext1 ; do
    for file2 in *.ext2 ; do
        # for each file ending with .ext2, verify if it is file1's corresponding pair
        # I know this is extremely time inefficient, since it's a O(n^2) operation, but I couldn't find another alternative
        if [[ "${file1%.*}" == "${file2%.*}" ]] ; then
            # extract file_number, and par1, par2 based on some conditions, then append to the csv file
            paste -d ',' "$file1" "$file2" | while IFS="," read -r var1 var2;
            do
                echo "$par1,$par2,$var1,$var2,$file_number" >> "file_out.csv" 
            done
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: [gnu getline with file](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fFile.html#Getline_002fFile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to efficiently do what your updated question describes:

> Suppose I have a directory with pairs of files, ending with two
>   extensions: .ext1 and .ext2. Those files have parameters included in
>   their names, for example file_0_par1_par2.ext1 has its pair,
>   file_0_par1_par2.ext2. Each file contains 5 values. I have a function
>   to extract its serial number and its parameters from its name. My goal
>   is to write, on a single csv file (file_out.csv), the values present
>   in the files along with the parameters extracted from their names.

```
for file1 in *.ext1 ; do
    for file2 in *.ext2 ; do
        # for each file ending with .ext2, verify if it is file1's corresponding pair
        # I know this is extremely time inefficient, since it's a O(n^2) operation, but I couldn't find another alternative
        if [[ "${file1%.*}" == "${file2%.*}" ]] ; then
            # extract file_number, and par1, par2 based on some conditions, then append to the csv file
            paste -d ',' "$file1" "$file2" | while IFS="," read -r var1 var2;
            do
                echo "$par1,$par2,$var1,$var2,$file_number" >> "file_out.csv" 
            done
        fi
    done
done
```

would be (untested):

```
for file1 in *.ext1; do
    base="${file1%.*}"
    file2="${base}.ext2"
    paste -d ',' "$file1" "$file2" |
    awk -v base="$base" '
        BEGIN { split(base,b,/_/); FS=OFS="," }
        { print b[3], b[4], $1, $2, b[2] }
    '
done > 'file_out.csv'
```

Doing `base="${file1%.*}"; file2="${base}.ext2"` itself would be N^2 times (given N pairs of files) more efficient than `for file2 in *.ext2 ; do if [[ "${file1%.*}" == "${file2%.*}" ]] ; then` and doing `| awk '...'` itself would be an order of magnitude more efficient than `| while IFS="," read -r var1 var2; do echo ...; done` (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) so you can expect to see a huge improvement in performance over your existing script.

Comment: Whu are you using `paste` when you are already using `awk`?  Perhaps start with `IFS=_ read -r _ _ par1 par2 <<< ${file1%.ext1};`, but this can be done in `awk` too.

Comment: @Walter because `paste | awk` will probably be more efficient than storing all of file1s values in memory in an awk array first and if the files are huge then paste will handle it by paging as necessary while awk would just fail, and it's less code to write and slightly simpler code to write. I am already doing that last part more simply and efficiently in awk using split().

Answer (score 2):

You can use yours solutions with "paste". Just add while loop for example to
take control for each iteration.

```
paste -d ',' file1 file2 | while IFS="," read -r lineA lineB;
do
    # you can build new file here like you need
    echo "$lineA,$lineB"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Your command fails:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$count]=$1; count+=1; next} {print a[$count] "," $1; count+=1;}' file1 file2 > file3
```

Don't use `$count` but `count`, start with count 1 and reset count to 1 when starting in file2. The last two conditions can be added by `FNR==1 {count=1}` or `{count=FNR}`.
When `count` is always the same as `FNR`, why use `count`?

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR] "," $1; }' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Two pieces of advice that might help:

First, I suspect an Awk script that does what you want will be too long for a one-liner. I would write a multi-line script that takes `file1` and `file2` as arguments, and store it in a file called `mymerge.awk` or whatever. Here is a skeleton:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    file1=ARGV[1]; file2=ARGV[2]
}

# The guts of your script go here.
```

Then you can simply make your script executable (`chmod +x mymerge.awk`) and call it from the shell: `mymerge.awk file1 file2`. This approach has the advantage of making your script easy to read, reuse, and maintain.

The second piece of advice: Use Awk's `getline < file1` to read data from `file1` instead of `stdin`. Likewise for `file2`. To store the lines you just read in variables, you can say

```
getline var1 < file1; getline var2 < file2
```

The Gnu Awk Users Guide has a comprehensive and readable [description of `getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile) and how to use it.

I won't be able to write and test a working script for you tonight, but I hope this will help you make some progress.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {getline file2_line < "file2.txt"; print $1","file2_line }' file1.txt
```

The begin block sets the field separator to comma, but this only applies to data in file1.txt

The first statement in the main body of the script stores the value of this line from file2.txt into a variable named file2_line.  This variable contains the **entire** line from file2.txt, and the data in the line is not split into fields in the usual fashion. This means that if file2.txt were also comma-delimited, you would probably want to use awk's split function to split the string into an array in order to work with the individual fields.

In awk, one concatenates by simply writing string values one after another, so `print $1","file2_line` writes the first field from the first file, a literal comma, and the string value for this line of file2.txt which we stored earlier.

Comment: If you're considering using getline then see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the caveats and ways to call it. Also the solution you posted should use `OFS=","` and `print $0, file2_line` rather than `FS=","` and `print $1","file2_line`. The statement `The begin block sets the field separator to comma, but this only applies to data in file1.txt` is just wrong.

Comment: OFS="," is a fine suggestion, but the field separator only applying to the file which was *not* opened using getline is not wrong.  It comes straight from the manual. "In this version of getline, none of the predefined variables are changed and the record is not split into fields." https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fFile.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fFile

Comment: Your statement is wrong (but the manual is correct), the field separator applies to all files, not just the data in file1.txt. The reason you don't see the effect of it is that you aren't doing field splitting since your getline is populating a variable rather than populating $0 so you aren't using FSs value. I now think I understand what you were trying to say (something like "we aren't using FS when reading from file2.txt") but I'm not sure anything like that needs to be said and the current statement is misleading because it sounds like you're saying FS only applies to cmd line files.